# using multiple adapters in same class

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I'm using multiple Base adapter in a fragment class, and switching them on button click,
**Problem -->** at onCreate set adapter 1 as default, when switching it to second, then firstly it calls first adapter then second.

> 09-10 13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-10 13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 09-10 13:07:46.396:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15742):  at
>   android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1163) 09-10
>   13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742):    at
>   android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
>   09-10 13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742):  at
>   android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155) 09-10
>   13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742):    at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:12853) 09-10 13:07:46.396:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15742):  at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:584)
>   09-10 13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742):  at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:397) 09-10
>   13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742):    at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:12853) 09-10 13:07:46.396:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15742):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4806)
>   09-10 13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742):  at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:298) 09-10
>   13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742):    at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:12853) 09-10 13:07:46.396:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15742):  at
>   android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:651)
>   09-10 13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742):  at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:12853) 09-10 13:07:46.396:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15742):  at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:599)
>   09-10 13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742):  at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:381) 09-10
>   13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742):    at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:12853) 09-10 13:07:46.396:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15742):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4806)
>   09-10 13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742):  at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:298) 09-10
>   13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742):    at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:12853) 09-10 13:07:46.396:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15742):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:829)
>   09-10 13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:558) 09-10
>   13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742):    at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:12853) 09-10 13:07:46.396:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15742):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4806)
>   09-10 13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742):  at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:298) 09-10
>   13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742):    at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2111)
>   09-10 13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742):  at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:12853) 09-10 13:07:46.396:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15742):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1065)
>   09-10 13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2455) 09-10
>   13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 09-10
>   13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 09-10 13:07:46.396:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15742):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 09-10
>   13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-10
>   13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 09-10 13:07:46.396:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15742):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
>   09-10 13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584) 09-10
>   13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: if you share your logcat we could be more helpful

Comment: @ Metehan in second adapter i'm using google map, first time when i open its working fine but second time it get crashed, u can check the log..

Comment: probably somewhere in the code you haven't set a variable(I think it's the listview).

Comment: @Metehan which class u talking about, adapter or fragment.

Comment: I'm not sure since you haven't shared any of your code here. And is this your full logcat? is there any other lines after `13:07:46.396: E/AndroidRuntime(15742): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`?

Comment: @Metehan It was the last line.

Comment: Can you share some code where you set your listviews?

Comment: @Metehan when i was searching for that, someone suggest me that getView returning null view, soi used

  if(view == null){
   LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trip_map_adapter, parent, false);
  }

just before returning view, it but it also not works

Answer (score 1):

When you want to switch you need to

```
 .setAdapter(null);
```

and then

```
.setAdapter(secondAdapter);
```

---

Also for your adapter:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.trip_map_adapter, null);
```